# Can !a!=!!b^!!-!a||!+!a|!c return anything other than 1?

Tags: javascript, logic

I was playing the Javascript game with somebody and we were having fun making ridiculous and absurd expressions to make our inputs get a particular output.

This little charming one

```
!a!=!!b^!!-!a||!+!a|!c
```

always seemed to return `1`. I tried to reason it out, but I gave up after losing track of all the `!`s.

Are there any values for `a`, `b`, and `c` which do not return `1`? If not, why does it always return `1`?

Comment: @Kevin: If you don't care, don't comment.

Comment: So you found a [tautology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic))?

Comment: I feel like I should draw up a Karnaugh map for this...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Short answer, yes.  `a = false, b = false, c = true` is a counter-example because your equation is identical to `(!!a || !!b || !c)`.

Long answer:

```
!a!=!!b^!!-!a||!+!a|!c
```

is

```
(((!a) != (!!b)) ^ (!!(-!a))) || ((!+!a)|!c)
```

which reduces to

```
((Boolean(a) == Boolean(b)) ^ (!a)) || (Boolean(a) | !c)
```

so all of `a`, `b` and `c` are only dealt with as truthy/falsey values and the result must be a `1` or `0` since `|` and `^` both coerce booleans to numbers.

So obviously (from inspection of the right of the `||`) if either `a` is truthy or `c` is falsey, you get `1`.

If `a` is falsey and `c` is truthy, you have two possibilities,

1. `b` is truthy in which case the `^` clause is `1` so the right of the `||` is never reached.
2. `b` is falsey, in which case the `^` clause is `0` so the right of the `||` dominates to produce `0`.

Comment: +1 Nice breakdown. I thought I had checked all of the boolean combinations, but I guess I didn't do it very carefully.

Comment: Best Answer!...and some extra stupid words to make this comment meet the min length requirements...

Comment: "Can __ return anything other than 1?" => "Short answer, no." => Example of how it can return something other than 1, so the short answer should be "yes"...

Comment: @Peter Generate a [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table); then you won't miss any combinations

Answer (score 9):

How about this:

```
var a = undefined, b=undefined, c=!a
alert(!a!=!!b^!!-!a||!+!a|!c)
// Output: 0
```

[Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/ctgA8/)

Comment: I made it so that your answer is more than a link to a resource that may become unavailable at any time.

Comment: Well played, but what about for defined values of a, b, c

Comment: Whether or not this is "cheating" is up to the OP.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr It looks like it works for any falsy value of `a` and `b` and truthy value of `c`.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr a=0,b=0,c=1 - output 0 :)

Answer (score 4):

Did you even try running it in a few loops:

```
for(var a = 0; a<100; a++) {
    for(var b = 0; b<100; b++) {  
        for(var c = 0; c<100; c++) {
            if((!a!=!!b^!!-!a||!+!a|!c) == 0) {
                console.log(a,b, c);
            }
        }
    }
}


a b c
=====
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 0 3
0 0 4
0 0 5
0 0 6
0 0 7
0 0 8
0 0 9
0 0 10
0 0 11
0 0 12
0 0 13
0 0 14
0 0 15
0 0 16
0 0 17
0 0 18
0 0 19
0 0 20
0 0 21
0 0 22
0 0 23
0 0 24
0 0 25
0 0 26
0 0 27
0 0 28
0 0 29
0 0 30
0 0 31
0 0 32
0 0 33
0 0 34
0 0 35
0 0 36
0 0 37
0 0 38
0 0 39
0 0 40
0 0 41
0 0 42
0 0 43
0 0 44
0 0 45
0 0 46
0 0 47
0 0 48
0 0 49
0 0 50
0 0 51
0 0 52
0 0 53
0 0 54
0 0 55
0 0 56
0 0 57
0 0 58
0 0 59
0 0 60
0 0 61
0 0 62
0 0 63
0 0 64
0 0 65
0 0 66
0 0 67
0 0 68
0 0 69
0 0 70
0 0 71
0 0 72
0 0 73
0 0 74
0 0 75
0 0 76
0 0 77
0 0 78
0 0 79
0 0 80
0 0 81
0 0 82
0 0 83
0 0 84
0 0 85
0 0 86
0 0 87
0 0 88
0 0 89
0 0 90
0 0 91
0 0 92
0 0 93
0 0 94
0 0 95
0 0 96
0 0 97
0 0 98
0 0 99
```

Comment: I had a triple nested loop lying around

Answer (score 3):

Try this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/ugfsW/

a=0, b=0, c=1 => Result : 0

The result is always **0** when you have [a=0, b=0](http://jsfiddle.net/wPBuU/1/) (c is not discriminant).
I assume that Domain(a) = Domain(b) = Domain(c)

Answer (score 1):

Some logical expressions are [tautologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_%28logic%29#Definition_and_examples), i.e., they're always true. It might be the case that you found one. Try to [verify it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_%28logic%29#Verifying_tautologies).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a model checker for this one. It will give you all the values which will output 0 or 1 :-) [Spin](http://spinroot.com/spin/whatispin.html) is a very popular model checker for example.